# spam classification - machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, classification, spam-prevention

I have to do spam detection application using a few classifiers(e.g. Naive Bayes, SVM and another one yet) and compare them efficiency but unfortunately I don't know what should I do exactly.

Is this correct:
Firstly I should have corpus spam such as trec2005, spamassasin or enron-spam.
Then, I do text pre-processing like stemming, stop words removal, tokenize, etc.

After that I can measure weight my features/terms in spam emails using tf-idf . 
Next I remove these features with very low and very high frequencies.
And I can classify my emails then. Right?

After that I can measure my correct classifications by true-positive, false-positive, etc..

If 10fold cross validation is required for something ?
How should I use it?

Could you tell me if these steps for email classifications are OK?
If not, please explain what are the correct steps for spam classification.

Comment: Stanford uses spam classification as an example in its machine learning classes both on [coursera](https://www.coursera.org/course/ml) and in Lecture 5 of [CS229](http://see.stanford.edu/see/lecturelist.aspx?coll=348ca38a-3a6d-4052-937d-cb017338d7b1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is roughly the steps you need to build a spam classifier:

1- **Input**:  a labeled training set that contains enough samples of spam and legitimate e-mails

2- **Feature Extraction**: convert your e-mail text into useful features for training e.g. stemming, remove stop words, words frequency. Then evaluate these features (i.e. apply attribute selection method) to select the most significant ones.

3- If you have large enough dataset, split it into training, validation and testing set. If not you can use your entire dataset for training and do cross validation to evaluate the classifier performance

4- **Train** your classifier and either use the testing dataste to evaluate its performance or do cross validation

5- Use the trained model to classify new e-mails. Done.

The use of cross validation is to evaluate your model performance on new/unseen data. So if you have an independent testing dataset you might not need cross validation at all, because you can evaluate the model performance on the testing dataset. However when your dataset is small you can divide it to subsets (e.g. 10 folds) and then repeat the training 10 times, every time you will use only 90% of your data and test on the remaining 10% and so on.

You will end up with 10 estimates of the classifier error average them to get the mean square or absolute error